# Why doesn't my code reverse string in c++?

Tags: c++

As a novice in c++, I try to use it could reverse a string with this

```
class Solution {
public:
    void reverses(string s,int begin,int end){
        char c;
        for(int i=begin,j=end-1;i<j;i++,j--){  
            c=s[i];  
            std::cout<<s[i]<<std::endl;
            s[i]=s[j];  
            s[j]=c;  
            std::cout<<s[j]<<std::endl;
        }  
    }
    string reverseLeftWords(string s, int n) {
        reverses(s,0,n);
        return s;
    }
};
```

But it give me the original string.
But when i use it in *char 
`

```
void Reverse(char *s,int n){  
    for(int i=0,j=n-1;i<j;i++,j--){  
        char c=s[i];  
        s[i]=s[j];  
        s[j]=c;  
    }  
}  

int main()  
{  
    char s[]="hello";  
    Reverse(s,5);
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it out put olleh, what's different between them?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: Also consider `std::swap`. You should also be careful with const char* string literals. I would expect your code to crash on some systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, you use a pointer to a character, which means that the function is changing the original string data, in place, which works. Contrast this with the first sample, where you pass in a `std::string` by value (meaning that the function is working on a copy of that string), reverse it in-place, and then discard the result.

If you want to use an `std::string` you can either take it by reference or by pointer-to-object:

```
void reverses(string& s,int begin,int end){
        char c;
        for(int i=begin,j=end-1;i<j;i++,j--){  
            c=s[i];  
            std::cout<<s[i]<<std::endl;
            s[i]=s[j];  
            s[j]=c;  
            std::cout<<s[j]<<std::endl;
        }  
    }
```

or

```
void reverses(string* s,int begin,int end){
        char c;
        for(int i=begin,j=end-1;i<j;i++,j--){  
            c=(*s)[i];  
            std::cout<<(*s)[i]<<std::endl;
            (*s)[i]=(*s)[j];  
            (*s)[j]=c;  
            std::cout<<(*s)[j]<<std::endl;
        }  
    }

    string reverseLeftWords(string s, int n) {
        reverses(&s,0,n);
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and example! It help me so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass your string a reference:

```
void reverses(string& s,int begin,int end){
```

Or return it as a result

```
string reverses(string s,int begin,int end){
   ...
   return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you so much! Good to know why it could not work!